# How determine if a token is part of an entity within Spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I have

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
line = "Rio de Janeiro is the capital of.."
doc = nlp(line)
for tok in doc:
    printf(tok.lemma_)
for ent in doc.ents:
    printf(e.lemma_)
```

I want obtain wikization: "[[Rio de Janeiro]] [[be|is]] [[the]] [[capital]] [[of]].."
how determine if token "Rio" is part of entity "Rio de Janeiro"?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `ent_type` or `ent_type_` attribute, if the value is not an empty string it is an entity.

Edit: for attribute `ent_iob` or `ent_iob_` *“B”* means the token begins an entity, *“I”* means it is inside an entity, *“O”* means it is outside an entity, and "" means no entity tag is set.

```
 import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    line = "Rio de Janeiro is the capital of.."
    doc = nlp(line)
    for tok in doc:
        print(tok, tok.ent_type_, tok.ent_iob_)
```

Output:

```
Rio GPE B
de GPE I
Janeiro GPE I
is  O
the  O
capital  O
of  O
..  O
```

Answer (score 2):

Entities have start and end property: indicies of token stream.
I can write:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
line = "Rio de Janeiro is the capital of.."
doc = nlp(line)
if len(doc.ents)>0:
    firstEnt = doc.ents[0].start
else:
    firstEnt = len(doc)
for j in range(firstEnt):
    print(doc[j])
j = firstEnt
for i in range(len(doc.ents)):
    ent = doc.ents[i]
    while j<ent.start:
        print(doc[j])
        j+=1
    print(ent)
if len(doc.ents) > 0:
    j = ent.end
while j<len(doc):
    print(doc[j])
    j+=1
```